# What is the highest recorded temperature in space

Tags: temperature

What is the highest recorded temperature in space? I'm not asking about Planck temperature that is a fraction of a second before the Big Bang. I'm asking about the temperature that has been recorded by an instrument.

Comment: I can't swear to the accuracy of this, but you might enjoy this video.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fuHzC9aTik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well [this infograhic](http://www.fromquarkstoquasars.com/coldest-hottest-temperatures-known-universe-infographic/) puts gas heated by a supernova at about 55 million Celsius.

And that's not even the highest temperature we can just "find" out there, even if we discard supernovae and stellar cores.  [The gas in a cluster of galaxies (the ICM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intracluster_medium) can have temperatures on the orders of 10 million to 100 million Kelvin.  Such a high temperature gas emits high energy photons such as X-rays via bremsstrahlung radiation, and these are observable (and have been observed) by X-ray telescopes.

There's [this review article](http://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0310557v1.pdf) from 2003 that covers the basic methodologies and measurements made on ICMs, including (but decidedly not limited to) temperature.